# Is there a durandal 2.1.0 nuget package based on Bootstrap 3.0 already?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, durandal

I'm about to start a project using Durandal,and I'd feel way more confident to start with Bootsrap 3.0.

Comment: Note that the latest release of Durandal at the time the question was asked is 2.0.1, not 2.1.0 -- to avoid any potential future confusion. 2.1.0 seems to be on the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Durandaljs doesn't have Bootstrap as a dependency and can be safely updated seperatly when needed.

As for a application template nuget package have a look at [HotTowel nuget Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HotTowel/)
It is based on Bootstrap 2.3.2 but it is reasonably trivial to update it to Bootstrap 3